# sort Dictionary by number of elemnts in List which is value for nested dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to sort dictionary by the number of elements in the List in the nested dictionary:
var evantData = new Dictionary>>()

This is my code..

```
    var evantData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>
    ();
    string input = "";

    while ((input=Console.ReadLine())!="Time for Code")
    {
        string[] evantAndParticipants = input.Split().Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

        if (!evantData.ContainsKey(evantAndParticipants[0]))
        {
            evantData.Add(evantAndParticipants[0],new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
            evantData[evantAndParticipants[0]].Add(evantAndParticipants[1], new List<string>());
        }
        evantData[evantAndParticipants[0]][evantAndParticipants[1]].AddRange(evantAndParticipants.Skip(2));

    }

    foreach (var item in evantData)
    {
        foreach (var evant in item.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(evant.Key+" - {0}",evant.Value.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n",evant.Value));
        }
    }
```

I want to sort the out by the number of elements in the List

Comment: what is the quesiton? show your code

Comment: Sort a dictionary????? There's no such notion as order of elements in a hashtable/dictionary. I suggest you familiarize yourself with the basic data structures that exist and the common operations on them as well as in what circumstances they are useful.

Comment: ok, to sort the out by number of elements in List<string>

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a dictionary is inherently wrong, it doesn't make sense.

Now, if what you need are only the values sorted in some given order and you don't need the associated keys then you can simply do:

```
 myDictionary.Values.OrderBy(v => v.Count);
```

If you need to sort the `KeyValuePair<,>` that make up your dictionary, then you can do:

```
var sortedKeyValuePairs = myDictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Value.Count);
```

But, this isn't normally what you'd want to do with a dictionary. You are either using the wrong tool or trying to do something the wrong way. Why do you need to do this?

Do note that none of the options above *sorts your dictionary*. You can't do that; they simply create new enumerations with the items stored in your dictionary sorted in the specified order.